# Javascript - How to loop through objects within objects that also contain arrays?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an object that contains objects as well as arrays --

```
const models = {
    characters: {
        human: {
            male: {
                short: [
                    { url: 'resources/models/characters/human/male/short/male0.fbx' },
                ],
                tall: [
                    { url: 'resources/models/characters/human/male/tall/male0.fbx' },
                ]
            },
            female: [
                { url: 'resources/models/characters/human/female/female0.fbx' },
                { url: 'resources/models/characters/human/female/female0.fbx' },
            ],
        },
        orc: {
            male: [
                
            ],
            female: [
                
            ],
        }
    },
    objects: {
        floors: {
            wood: [
                { url: 'resources/models/objects/floors/wood/floor_wood_000.obj' },
                { url: 'resources/models/objects/floors/wood/floor_wood_001.obj' },
                { url: 'resources/models/objects/floors/wood/floor_wood_002.obj' },
                { url: 'resources/models/objects/floors/wood/floor_wood_003.obj' }
            ],
        },
        walls: {
            wood: [
                
            ],
        },
        stairs: {
            wood: [
                
            ],
        },
        bed: [
            { url: 'resources/models/objects/bed/objects_bed_mattress_000.obj' },
            { url: 'resources/models/objects/bed/objects_bed_mattress_000.obj' }
        ],
    }
};

var count = {
    characters: numberOfUrlsInCharacters,
    objects: numberofUrlsInObjects
};
```

Now I want to count how many `URLs` in total the object `models` contains. Would I have to count this manually, or is there an easier way?

Also, notice the objects are not equal. They all contain different amount of objects & arrays.

Comment: what is your specific problem? what have you tried?

Comment: The code in your post is invalid.

Comment: There isn't an object called `model` just `models`.  So you want to count all the urls in all the models, right?

Comment: This is when you need a recursive descent parser

Comment: @James sorry, I fixed the question. Yes )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned that the structure of the data is not consistent, it would make your task very easy if you `stringify` the object, and then look for the keyword `"url":` to get a count of the URLs present.

```
const strigifiedModels = JSON.stringify(models);

const count = (strigifiedModels.match(/"url":/g) || []).length;
```

Working snippet:

```js
const models = {
  characters: {
    human: {
      male: {
        short: [{
          url: 'resources/models/characters/human/male/short/male0.fbx'
        }, ],
        tall: [{
          url: 'resources/models/characters/human/male/tall/male0.fbx'
        }, ],
        female: [{
            url: 'resources/models/characters/human/female/female0.fbx'
          },
          {
            url: 'resources/models/characters/human/female/female0.fbx'
          },
        ],
      },
      orc: {
        male: [],
        female: [],
      },
    },
    objects: {
      floors: {
        wood: [{
            url: 'resources/models/objects/floors/wood/floor_wood_000.obj'
          },
          {
            url: 'resources/models/objects/floors/wood/floor_wood_001.obj'
          },
          {
            url: 'resources/models/objects/floors/wood/floor_wood_002.obj'
          },
          {
            url: 'resources/models/objects/floors/wood/floor_wood_003.obj'
          },
        ],
      },
      walls: {
        wood: [],
      },
      stairs: {
        wood: [],
      },
      bed: [{
          url: 'resources/models/objects/bed/objects_bed_mattress_000.obj'
        },
        {
          url: 'resources/models/objects/bed/objects_bed_mattress_000.obj'
        },
      ],
    },
  },
};

const strigifiedModels = JSON.stringify(models);

const count = (strigifiedModels.match(/"url":/g) || []).length;

console.log(count);
```

Comment: This is a brilliant solution, it saves a lot of time from recursive nonsense.

Comment: Just don't put "url:" anywhere in a string element.

Comment: Cool! Would this still work if I wanted to separate the url counts for each the Characters, and Objects ? Since that is my main goal. I didn't mention, but have updated my question

Comment: Solution would work, need to do  `JSON.stringify(models.characters)` and one for  objects.

Answer (score 2):

Recursive Nonsense:

```js
const models = {
    characters: {
        human: {
            male: {
                short: [
                    { url: 'resources/models/characters/human/male/short/male0.fbx' },
                ],
                tall: [
                    { url: 'resources/models/characters/human/male/tall/male0.fbx' },
                ]
            },
            female: [
                { url: 'resources/models/characters/human/female/female0.fbx' },
                { url: 'resources/models/characters/human/female/female0.fbx' },
            ],
        },
        orc: {
            male: [
                
            ],
            female: [
                
            ],
        }
    },
    objects: {
        floors: {
            wood: [
                { url: 'resources/models/objects/floors/wood/floor_wood_000.obj' },
                { url: 'resources/models/objects/floors/wood/floor_wood_001.obj' },
                { url: 'resources/models/objects/floors/wood/floor_wood_002.obj' },
                { url: 'resources/models/objects/floors/wood/floor_wood_003.obj' }
            ],
        },
        walls: {
            wood: [
                
            ],
        },
        stairs: {
            wood: [
                
            ],
        },
        bed: [
            { url: 'resources/models/objects/bed/objects_bed_mattress_000.obj' },
            { url: 'resources/models/objects/bed/objects_bed_mattress_000.obj' }
        ],
    }
};


const countUrls = (thing) => {
  let count = 0;
  if (Array.isArray(thing)) {
    count += thing.reduce((acc, el) => acc + countUrls(el), 0);
  } else if (typeof thing === "object") {
    if (thing.url) {
      count++;
    } else {
      count += Object.values(thing).reduce((acc, el) => acc + countUrls(el), 0);
    }
  }
  return count;
};

console.log(countUrls(models));

console.log(countUrls(models.characters.human));
```

Comment: I think @Rohit Jindal 's version best suits my needs and is more simplified. But thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this **:**

```js
const models = {
    characters: {
        human: {
            male: {
                short: [
                    { url: 'resources/models/characters/human/male/short/male0.fbx' },
                ],
                tall: [
                    { url: 'resources/models/characters/human/male/tall/male0.fbx' },
                ]
            },
            female: [
                { url: 'resources/models/characters/human/female/female0.fbx' },
                { url: 'resources/models/characters/human/female/female0.fbx' },
            ],
        },
        orc: {
            male: [
                
            ],
            female: [
                
            ],
        }
    },
    objects: {
        floors: {
            wood: [
                { url: 'resources/models/objects/floors/wood/floor_wood_000.obj' },
                { url: 'resources/models/objects/floors/wood/floor_wood_001.obj' },
                { url: 'resources/models/objects/floors/wood/floor_wood_002.obj' },
                { url: 'resources/models/objects/floors/wood/floor_wood_003.obj' }
            ],
        },
        walls: {
            wood: [
                
            ],
        },
        stairs: {
            wood: [
                
            ],
        },
        bed: [
            { url: 'resources/models/objects/bed/objects_bed_mattress_000.obj' },
            { url: 'resources/models/objects/bed/objects_bed_mattress_000.obj' }
        ],
    }
};

const numberOfUrlsInCharacters = JSON.stringify(models.characters).match(/"url":/ig).length;
const numberofUrlsInObjects = JSON.stringify(models.objects).match(/"url":/ig).length;

var count = {
    characters: numberOfUrlsInCharacters,
    objects: numberofUrlsInObjects
};

console.log(count);
```

Comment: Took it 1 step further, added --  for( var i in models ) { numberOfUrls[i]= JSON.stringify(models[i]).match(/"url":/ig).length; }   -- Works perfectly :) Thank you!

Comment: @VardanBetikyan Yeah I added `i` in the regex if in case you have `URL` property in upper case in any of the object. Also, I seperated counts for `characters` and `objects` seperately.

Comment: I think technically Aneesh answered first, so I think fair if I accept his answer. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: @VardanBetikyan Sure. No issues :)

Answer (score 1):

Recursive look up. Just assumes that `url` will aways be in array of objects.

```js
const models = {
  characters: {
    human: {
      male: {
        short: [{
          url: 'resources/models/characters/human/male/short/male0.fbx'
        }, ],
        tall: [{
          url: 'resources/models/characters/human/male/tall/male0.fbx'
        }, ]
      },
      female: [{
          url: 'resources/models/characters/human/female/female0.fbx'
        },
        {
          url: 'resources/models/characters/human/female/female0.fbx'
        },
      ],
    },
    orc: {
      male: [

      ],
      female: [

      ],
    }
  },
  objects: {
    floors: {
      wood: [{
          url: 'resources/models/objects/floors/wood/floor_wood_000.obj'
        },
        {
          url: 'resources/models/objects/floors/wood/floor_wood_001.obj'
        },
        {
          url: 'resources/models/objects/floors/wood/floor_wood_002.obj'
        },
        {
          url: 'resources/models/objects/floors/wood/floor_wood_003.obj'
        }
      ],
    },
    walls: {
      wood: [

      ],
    },
    stairs: {
      wood: [

      ],
    },
    bed: [{
        url: 'resources/models/objects/bed/objects_bed_mattress_000.obj'
      },
      {
        url: 'resources/models/objects/bed/objects_bed_mattress_000.obj'
      }
    ],
  }
};


const countUrls = (item) => {
  if (Array.isArray(item)) {
    return item.reduce((c, x) => x.url ? c + 1 : c, 0);
  } else {
    return Object.values(item).reduce((cnt, x) =>
      cnt + countUrls(x), 0);
  }
}


const result = Object.entries(models).reduce((acc, [key, obj]) => {
  acc[key] = countUrls(obj);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think @Rohit Jindal 's version best suits my needs and simplified. But thank you :)

Comment: @VardanBetikyan only issue with that solution is it can return wrong values if the string happens to match.

Comment: in my specific case, the url strings represent file paths of resources, so each url will be unique